# Azure WorkerRole PaaS Symantec Endpoint Protection

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, symantec

I have azure c# WorkerRole (PaaS) where I need to check uploaded files for viruses.
And I am going to use Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP) DoScan.exe utility.

I need to create deployment script which will automatically install and setup SEP on WorkerRole.

Can you advice, please, how to setup and configure SEP using installation scripts (not using SEP GUI)?

I found insturctions how to setup SEP on Azure VM here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-install-symantec/

But it is for Azure VM not for WorkerRole.